# Página de proyecto para portfolio en PHP con friendly URL con .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

No soy un experto en PHP pero he elegido este método porque puedo incluir contenido de otros archivos más pequeños para no repetir el contenido. Creo que también se puede hacer con React y Vue, pero ya tengo toda la base de datos estructurada, aunque si es recomendable, pues me plantearía aprender esos otros métodos.

El caso es que ya tengo toda mi estructura de carpetas, algo parecido a esto:

```
/proyecto/
    index.php
    about.php
    proyectos.php
    ver-proyecto.php

    /inc/
        header.php
        footer.php
        ...
    /img/
        ...
    /js/
        ...
```

Mediante .htaccess he conseguido poder acceder a través de `example.com/proyectos` y `example.com/proyecto-primer-titulo`, pero quería que fuera `example.com/proyectos/primer-titulo` y que si al borrar en la barra de búsqueda llega hasta `example.com/proyectos/`, no diera error y fuera redirigido a `example.com/proyectos`

Adjunto la parte de Rewrite del .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /

  #### PERSISTENT CONTENT ####

  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php


  RewriteRule ^proyecto-(.*)$ ver-proyecto.php?id=$1
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes eliminar los trailing slashes con la siguiente condición:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: ¿Has leído la pregunta? Necesito solución a lo primero

Comment: Te estoy respondiendo la segunda pregunta.